# Rearranging Windows 8 tiles within a group

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, live-tiles

How do I effectively rearrange Windows 8 tiles within a single group. It seems to behave erratically. If I move a tile to one slot to the left or right, it behaves as expected. However, moving it more seems to rearrange other tiles that are picked at random from another row.

This is EXTREMELY annoying and I have stopped using Metro altogether. Any suggestions on how to arrange within groups?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way the Metro grid is designed. Auto-arrange goes from the top left two tiles wide and then starts a new row. It confusing to explain and easier show through demonstration. I just let it be. It's irritating and there is no efficient way to arrange tiles. It's like a puzzle.